# Split Single Mysqli data into seperate variables

Tags: php

Is it possible to split a single column data and store it in different variables?

Like

```
SELECT telephone FROM contacts WHERE id='1';
```

the value of telephone is XXX-XXX-XXXX

```
$first = '(first)';
$second= '(second)';
$third= '(third)';
$dash = '(dash)';
```

Comment: You can use explode method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$telNumber = "123-345-6789";
$telArray = explode("-",$telNumber);

$first = $telArray[0]; //123
$second= $telArray[1]; //345
$third= $telArray[2];  //6789
```